# protractor expect statement returning number instead of text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, testing, protractor

i currently have a html that I am trying to test with protractor.
I am trying to test that when the user clicks either "Mr", "Ms" or "Mrs" from a drop down list that my expect statement will pass. 
this is what I have so far:

```
iit('should input correct first name', function(){
        browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#btn39')).click();
        var title = element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Ms')).click();
        expect(title.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Ms');
    });
```

the error I get is that it is saying expected 1 to equal 'Ms'. If I change `('option', 'Ms'))` to `('option', 'Mrs'))`. it says expected 2 to equal 'Mrs'. It is obviously finding their position within the list rather than returning their actual value. so it is half working, how can I replace the numbered positions with their corresponding values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can always get the innerHTML instead of the value if the value is not set in your HTML.

```
expect(title.getAttribute('innerHTML')).toBe('Ms');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually called a [**text** of an element](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText):

```
expect(title.getText()).toBe('Ms');
```